# Python Scheduled Script to a docker container

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning, scikit-learn, containers

I have built a RandomForest Regression model as a python script. It accepts two csv files train and test, performs training and testing. It then prints the predictions and accuracy and finally saved the predictions as csv file. 
I have saved the code file as RandomForest.py. After which I have created a batch execution (.bat) file for RandomForest.py. After that I have used Windows Task Scheduler to schedule my Python Script(RandomForest.py) to run once a week. After that I have exported the scheduled task as a '.xml' file.
My Question: I want to put this .xml file inside a docker container so that it runs itself once a week.

RandomForest.py code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd


class Modelrf():

    def __init__(self, train = "train.csv", test = "test.csv"):
        self.X_train = pd.read_csv(train)
        self.X_test = pd.read_csv(test)
        self.linear_reg = LinearRegression()
        self.random_forest = RandomForestRegressor()
    def split(self):
        self.X_train.dropna(axis=0, subset=['final_hourly_fee'], inplace=True)
        self.X_test.dropna(axis=0, subset=['final_hourly_fee'], inplace=True)
        self.y_train = self.X_train.final_hourly_fee
        self.y_test = self.X_test.final_hourly_fee

    def fit(self):
        self.model = self.random_forest.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)

    def predict(self):

        self.result = self.random_forest.predict(self.X_test)
        return self.result



model_instance = Modelrf()
model_instance.split()
model_instance.fit()
model_instance.predict()
print(model_instance.result)
print("Accuracy: ", model_instance.model.score(model_instance.X_test, model_instance.y_test))

output = pd.DataFrame({'Id': model_instance.X_test.index,'Y Original': model_instance.y_test, 'Y predicted':model_instance.result})
output.to_csv('outputTest.csv', index=False)
```

.bat file:

```
python C:\Python\Headstrt\gitlab_pricing\myproject.git\RandomForest.py

pause
```

Comment: if I'm not mistaken a .bat files is for running only on windows, If your docker container is linux... Ubuntu for example, then you need to create a bash script.

I would suggest taking a look into Apache airflow ( implemented in python) and it's ideal for scheduling jobs. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/start.html

Comment: I want it inside a container so that later on I can move it to cloud.

Comment: I understand, could you specify which OS you intend to use on the docker container ? linux, windows?

you can easily run airflow inside a container. I  will try to write a quick answer showing how to how a scheduled task in airflow. take a look :https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html

Comment: Windows operating system.

Comment: Shame you didn't get any worthwhile answers as this is good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a [cron job in the docker container](https://blog.knoldus.com/running-a-cron-job-in-docker-container/).

This cron string will run once a week `0 0 * * 0`. Got this from [here](https://crontab.guru/every-week).

Comment: Here's a guide on how to create a cron job to run a python script: https://medium.com/@gavinwiener/how-to-schedule-a-python-script-cron-job-dea6cbf69f4e